# What is SPSite.OutgoingEmailAddress used for?

Tags: 2013

Does anyone know what the SPSite.OutgoingEmailAddress property is used for?
By default it is set to the same value as the WebApplication.OutboundMailSenderAddress.  However, I can update it via powershell and notifications are still sent from the WebApplication.OutboundMailSenderAddress address.

Comment: I don't see that property in PowerShell or the OM on SPSite.